# Inserting a formula using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to insert an IF formula using a macro and I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Trying to insert quotes has me confused, attempting to insert "" I have to use """"".

This is the **IF** function I need to insert

```
=IF(P14&Q14&R14<>"","<>","")
```

The macro creates a new row every time it is called, therefore the next formula inserted under it would be

```
=IF(P15&Q15&R15<>"","<>","")
```

I get the next empty row using

```
   iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, 
_ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues.Row + 1
```

Yet using this insert method and syntax I get a type mismatch error.

```
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = "=IF(P" + iRow + "&Q" + iRow + "&R" + iRow + "<>"""""," + ""<>"",""""")"
```

Can someone please advise as to why I am receiving a type mismatch error?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I paste many formulae using a macro from a template to the worksheet. I have all the formulae on the template without the "=" at the front so that vba&excel sees them as text. Infact, the "=" is replaced by "xyxy" so once the paste operation is complete I do a find/replace for "xyxy" with "=" an d all work- well works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not use `+` for concatenation. Use `&`. In some particular cases, you may have problems.

Secondly, it is good to use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`...

And the formula string should be:

```
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = "=IF(P" & iRow & "&Q" & iRow & "&R" & iRow & "<>""""," & """<>"","""")"
```

Five `"""""` makes sense only at the end of the string... Four to double the existing one and the fifth for string termination.

Comment: In this particular case it's a bit *tit for tat* when you say "you must use..." since `.Value` will work just as well for inserting a formula. However, I guess you are right if it's more appropriate =) +

Comment: @JvdV: I do not say it will not work! In fact, in this specific case, using `+` for concatenation will work, too, since it is used between a string and a number, but I only wanted to emphasize some clean ways of cultivating his programming habits... It is good to know what you wanted doing when try debugging, I think.

Comment: Offcourse, it simply looks more appropriate too. Just mentioned it as a FYI.

Comment: @JvdV: But, maybe you are right. I will change "must" with "it will be good"...

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Replace("=IF(PX&QX&RX<>"""",""<>"","""")", "X", iRow)
```